# Can we use the above result to get the asymptotic limit of the derivative of the moment generating function $\frac{d}{dt} E[e^{tX}]$?

Tags: probability, analysis, random-matrices

Let $X\sim \mu$ be a random variable taking value on $R$. Assume that $d\mu=C\sqrt{4-x^2}dx $ for some normalized constant $C>0$. Assume that the limit of moment generating function
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{E[e^{tX}]}{t^{-3/2}e^{2t}}=1.
$$

Can we use the above result to get the asymptotic limit of the derivative of the moment generating function $\frac{d}{dt} E[e^{tX}]=E[Xe^{tX}]$?

---

I try to find a relation between $E[Xe^{tX}]$ and $E[e^{tX}]$.

Note that
$$
E[e^{tX}]=C\int_{-2}^2e^{tx}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx.
$$

Comment: In general, one cannot differentiate asymptotic relations, but you may want to have a look at Tauberian theorems.

Comment: @nejimban Yes, I know. Is there any other method?

Comment: I just saw your edits. You actually *know* that $X$ has a semicircular distribution. The Laplace transform (moment generating function) is given by a Bessel function. It is a special function but derivatives and asymptotics of Bessel functions are known.

Comment: @nejimban Thanks. But how to get this one is given by a Bessel function? Is there any reference?

Comment: [This paragraph on Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution#General_properties) gives the characteristic function ($R=2$ in your case) and cites the sources [1], [2], [3], and [§9.6.18](https://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/index2.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.sfu.ca%2F%7Ecbm%2Faands%2Fpage_376.htm). I guess one way to show that $E[\mathrm e^{tX}]=\frac{J_1(2t)}t$ is to check that both $E[\mathrm e^{tX}]$ and $\frac{J_1(2t)}t$ (as functions of $t$) satisfy the same characteristic differential equation (with appropriate initial value/boundary conditions).

Comment: FYI: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{E[X\mathrm e^{tX}]}{t^{-3/2}\,\mathrm e^{2t}}=\frac1{\sqrt\pi},$$
so probably Tauberian theorems cannot apply here (at least it does not match the derivative of the asymptotics of $E[\mathrm e^{tX}]$)…

Comment: @nejimban Thank you very much! I think I can get the limit of $E[e^{tX}]$ by $J_1(2t)/t$ now. But how about the $\frac{d}{dt} E[e^{tX}]=-t^{-2}J_1(2t)+2t^{-1}J_1'(2t)$? Here we need the asymptotic limit of $J_1'(2t)$. I only found the asymptotic limit of $J_1(2t)$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177118/about-the-asymptotic-formula-of-bessel-function

Comment: Good. I think $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\,E[\mathrm e^{tX}]$ can be simplified to $$\frac{2 I_2(2 t)}{t^2}+\frac{4 I_3(2 t)}{t}$$ using the differential equation satisfied by the Bessel function $J_1$.

Comment: (Sorry I mixed up characteristic function and m.g.f in an earlier comment. I hope you can wrap your head around this, I am not fan of tedious computations :).)

Comment: @nejimban Sorry, I did not get your $d E[e^{tX}]/dt$. I found $J_0(x)-J_3(x)=2J_1'(x)$.

Comment: Also, I found $I_1'(x)=(I_0(x)+I_3(x))/2$, then $\frac{d}{dt}E[e^{tX}]=I_0(2t)/t-I_1(2t)/t^2+I_3(2t)/t$..

Comment: @nejimban So it seems that $I_2(x)\sim x^{-1/2}e^x$ and $I_3(x)\sim x^{-1/2}e^x$ as $x\to \infty$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791588/leading-terms-in-asymptotic-expansion-of-modified-bessel-function-of-the-first-k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving it a try I found that it's probably easier to deal with hypergeometric functions (which encompass all Bessel functions): start by [representing $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Special_and_limiting_cases) as $2(2Y-1)$ where $Y$ has a Beta$(\frac32,\frac32)$ distribution.
[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Moment_generating_function)
$$M(t):=E\!\left[\mathrm e^{tX}\right]=\mathrm e^{-2t}E\!\left[\mathrm e^{4tY}\right]=\mathrm e^{-2t}\cdot{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t),$$
where $_1F_1$ is [Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer%27s_equation). Its [asymptotic behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Asymptotic_behavior) is known:
$$_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t)\sim\frac{\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(\tfrac32)}\cdot\mathrm e^{4t}(4t)^{-\frac32}=\frac{\mathrm e^{4t}t^{-\frac32}}{2\sqrt\pi}.\tag{1}$$
Therefore $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{M(t)}{t^{-\frac32}\mathrm e^{2t}}=\color{red}{\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}}$$
(and not $1$). For the derivative, we have
$$M'(t)=\mathrm e^{-2t}\left(-2\cdot{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t)+4\cdot\partial_t\,{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t)\right).$$
The [derivative of Kummer's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Contiguous_relations) gives
$$
\partial_t\,{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t)=-\frac12\cdot{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;4;4t)+{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t),
$$
where ${}_1F_1(\tfrac32;4;4t)=O\bigl(\mathrm e^{4t}t^{-\frac52}\bigr)$ is negligible as $t\to\infty$ compared to (1). Then
$$
\partial_t\,{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t)\sim{}_1F_1(\tfrac32;3;4t).$$
Thus we can conclude that $M'(t)\sim 2M(t)$, and $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{E[X\mathrm e^{tX}]}{t^{-3/2}\,\mathrm e^{2t}}=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}.$$

Comment: Remark. The log-derivative of $M(t)$ is $$\frac{M'(t)}{M(t)}=\frac{2 I_2(2 t)}{I_1(2 t)}.$$