# How to approximate this integral

Tags: laplace-method

I am trying to approximate an integral of the following form
$$
F_n = \int_{-1}^1(1-u^2)^{(n-3)/2}e^{Anu}du
$$

(I am trying to work through this paper....https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6875199)

I am just not seeing the substitution I need to use to easily see which neighborhoods of u dominate.  Do I need to solve for the maximum of whats in the integral and use that as a guide? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What info do you have available about the value of the parameters $n, A$? Are you considering the case when $n$ is large? $A$? Both?

Comment: A is a fixed positive value. Yes I am trying to understand the behavior as $n\to\infty$.  Thank you for the question.

Comment: I think I see the solution.  I just need to write it like
$$
\int_{-1}^1e^{\frac{n-3}{2}\log (1-u^2)}e^{nAu} du
$$
and then it becomes a complicated but straightforward Laplace approximation problem. Thanks again for the question.

Comment: In that case I encourage you to write up and post your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} (1-u^2)^a\,e^{b u}\,du\quad\quad \text{with}\quad a>0\quad \text{and}\quad b>0$$

I think that the simplest way is to use the binomial expansion
$$(1-u^2)^a=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-a+k-1)!}{(-a-1)!\, k!}\,u^{2k}$$
$$\int_{-1}^{+1}u^{2k}\,e^{bu}\,du=-E_{-2 k}(-b)-E_{-2 k}(b)$$
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} (1-u^2)^a\,e^{b u}\,du=\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (a+1)\,\, \,
   _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{2a+3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4}\right)$$ which has the good idea to simplify
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} (1-u^2)^a\,e^{b u}\,du=\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (a+1)\,\, \,\left(\frac{2}{b}\right)^{\frac{2a+1}{2}}\,\, \,I_{\frac{2a+1}{2}}(b)$$

You can also arrive to this result using the definition of the  modified Bessel function of the first kind with a simple change of variable  such as $u=\cos(x)$ for example.

So, back to the notations
$$F_n=\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\,\, \,\left(\frac{2}{A n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,\, \,I_{\frac{n-2}{2}}(A n)$$

Now, using (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791588/leading-terms-in-asymptotic-expansion-of-modified-bessel-function-of-the-first-k))

$$\sqrt{x}\,\pi\, e^{-x}\,I_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( 1+ \frac{1-4n^2}{8x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\log(F_n)=\frac{2 A-\log (A)-1}{2} n +\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi  }{64 A}n\right)-\frac{96 A+37}{12 n}+ O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Trying for $A=\pi$ and $n=50$ gives
$$\log(F_{50})=102.774$$ while
$$\log\Big[\int_{-1}^{+1}\left(1-u^2\right)^{47/2}\,e^{50 \pi  u} \,du\Big]=100.834$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

I am having trouble getting to
$$\int_{-1}^{+1} (1-u^2)^a\,e^{b u}\,du=\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (a+1)\,\, \,
   _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{2a+3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4}\right)$$
 
I can see you start by rewriting the integral in terms of the expansion, but I am unclear how you get your result.