# Finding the leading order asymptotic approximation

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, bessel-functions

Find the leading order asymptotics of $$I_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x\cos(\theta)}\cos(n\theta)d\theta$$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Here's my work:

I am using the Laplace method: $\cos(\theta)$ has a (unique) max at $c=0\in(-\pi,\pi)$, $-\sin(0)=0$, and $-\cos(0)<0$. $\cos(\theta)$ is smooth and $\cos(n\theta)$ is continuous.

So then, we use $c=0$ since the main contribution comes from $c$ to approximate i.e. replace $\cos(n\theta)$ with $\cos(0)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ with the expansion of $\cos(0)-\sin(0)(\theta-0)-\frac{\cos(0)(\theta-0)^2}{2}$.

Then, $$I_n(x)\sim \frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(0)e^{x\cos(0)}\sqrt{\frac{-2\pi}{-x\cos(0)}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^x\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}$$
as $x \to +\infty$.

Am I right or on the right track? I don't have much experience with asymptotic expansion of integrals so I am having trouble with the reading on what I can find (e.g. Laplace Method, etc.) I also tried to follow [Leading terms in asymptotic expansion of modified bessel function of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791588/leading-terms-in-asymptotic-expansion-of-modified-bessel-function-of-the-first-k) due to the similiarity of the problem, but wasn't able to arrive at a solid understanding.

Comment: You should mention at the beginning that you are using Laplace's method. Mention that $0$ is the unique maximum point on the interval. Also note that $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^x\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$. Your final result is correct.

Comment: Edited. Thank you!